# Stripping out HTML tags from a string

Tags: html, ios, swift

How do I remove HTML tags from a string so that I can output clean text?

```
let str = string.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<[^>]+>", withString: "", options: .RegularExpressionSearch, range: nil)
print(str)
```

Comment: [Just use an HTML parser.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Led, this question has a lot of value but as-is, it is likely to get closed because you don't ask a clear question: it is a non-reproducible scenario. I suggest you rephrase your question as per [ask]. I wouldn't want that question to be deleted.

Comment: lol stackoverflow... how is this closed as "off topic"? It's the #1 google result for "Swift remove html tags".

Comment: @canhazbits i know right! Click reopen to nominate it to reopen again.

Comment: Swift 3: string.replacingOccurrences(of: "<[^>]+>", with: " ", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)

Answer (score 182, accepted):

Hmm, I tried your function and it worked on a small example:

```
var string = "<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <body> <h1>My First Heading</h1> <p>My first paragraph.</p> </body> </html>"
let str = string.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<[^>]+>", withString: "", options: .RegularExpressionSearch, range: nil)
print(str)

//output "  My First Heading My first paragraph. "
```

Can you give an example of a problem?

Swift 4 and 5 version:

```
var string = "<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <body> <h1>My First Heading</h1> <p>My first paragraph.</p> </body> </html>"
let str = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "<[^>]+>", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
```

Comment: [This does not always work: HTML is not a regular language, consequently regular expressions are not able to parse HTML.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: For example, try this piece of HTML: `<p foo=">now what?">Paragraph</p>`

Comment: **In Swift 3** `string.replacingOccurrences(of: "<[^>]+>",
                                    with: "",
                                    options: String.CompareOptions.regularExpression,
                                    range: nil)`

Comment: @Husam thanks for the swift3 version, but at a textview i get something like this `&lt;p&gt` etc. Do you know why ?

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios so sorry I don't know, and I don't have the chance to do a research , Excuse me

Comment: @SteveRosenberg beautiful answer Sir. Thanks a lot. I integrated text to speech from html page using your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Is it possible to save the spaces and line breaks while we remove html tags? Currently, all line breaks are disregarded in the new string.

Comment: In Swift 4 string.replacingOccurrences(of: "<[^>]+>", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)

Comment: This is not a proper solution and a huge pitfall, use a proper library to handle this (NSAttributedString on iOS is the only one built in). It won't properly handle text spacing, example converting <br> to \n. In some cases you will end up with garbage, as the content inside of <tags> is not often user visible text, for example <style> and <script>. html2text is a nice command line utility that seems to handle these cases, but it is sadly GPL licensed.

Answer (score 38):

Since HTML is not a [regular language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) (HTML is a [context-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) language), you cannot use Regular Expressions.  See: [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/590789/448287)

I would consider using NSAttributedString instead.

```
let htmlString = "LCD Soundsystem was the musical project of producer <a href='http://www.last.fm/music/James+Murphy' class='bbcode_artist'>James Murphy</a>, co-founder of <a href='http://www.last.fm/tag/dance-punk' class='bbcode_tag' rel='tag'>dance-punk</a> label <a href='http://www.last.fm/label/DFA' class='bbcode_label'>DFA</a> Records. Formed in 2001 in New York City, New York, United States, the music of LCD Soundsystem can also be described as a mix of <a href='http://www.last.fm/tag/alternative%20dance' class='bbcode_tag' rel='tag'>alternative dance</a> and <a href='http://www.last.fm/tag/post%20punk' class='bbcode_tag' rel='tag'>post punk</a>, along with elements of <a href='http://www.last.fm/tag/disco' class='bbcode_tag' rel='tag'>disco</a> and other styles. <br />"    
let htmlStringData = htmlString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
let options: [String: AnyObject] = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: NSUTF8StringEncoding]
let attributedHTMLString = try! NSAttributedString(data: htmlStringData, options: options, documentAttributes: nil)
let string = attributedHTMLString.string
```

Or, as Irshad Mohamed in the comments would do it:

```
let attributed = try NSAttributedString(data: htmlString.data(using: .unicode)!, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
print(attributed.string)
```

Comment: This seems to be the cleanest approach and it works wonderfully well! It's best to let the battle-tested Foundation framework handle this for you, instead of writing flaky parsers on your own.

Comment: Clean!! `let attributed = try NSAttributedString(data: htmlString.data(using: .unicode)!, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
                            print(attributed.string)` most people prefer to choose answers which are small and easy to understand.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Is it possible to save the spaces and line breaks while we remove html tags? Currently, all line breaks are disregarded in the new string.

Comment: Just a warning using this: ***HTML style converting (attributing) slow!***. A CoreText engineer at WWDC told me this is no longer maintained and he had forgotten entirely about it.

Comment: Just a warning about the previous warning: Let's see some data before we discard a method for being too "slow". There are plenty of C libraries that you use (often without realising it) that don't require much maintenance. That's not necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: I see this is old, but it's worth noting: this actually is slow, and it's because it pretty much loads a Webkit instance in the background to handle it.

Comment: There's a one off hit when first using this as it does require some initial setup (much like any NS formatter), but the actual processing of the HTML is demonstrably **not** slow.

Comment: It is, absolutely, unequivocally, **demonstrably slow**. Just try doing this with more than one string, or even better, just measure the time it takes to return in a synchronous context.

Answer (score 28):

Mohamed solution but as a String extension in Swift 4.

```
extension String {

    func stripOutHtml() -> String? {
        do {
            guard let data = self.data(using: .unicode) else {
                return nil
            }
            let attributed = try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
            return attributed.string
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I'm using the following extension to remove specific HTML elements:

```
extension String {
    func deleteHTMLTag(tag:String) -> String {
        return self.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("(?i)</?\(tag)\\b[^<]*>", withString: "", options: .RegularExpressionSearch, range: nil)
    }

    func deleteHTMLTags(tags:[String]) -> String {
        var mutableString = self
        for tag in tags {
            mutableString = mutableString.deleteHTMLTag(tag)
        }
        return mutableString
    }
}
```

This makes it possible to only remove `<a>` tags from a string, e.g.:

```
let string = "my html <a href="">link text</a>"
let withoutHTMLString = string.deleteHTMLTag("a") // Will be "my  html link text"
```

Comment: @Mr Lister is there a way to remove all html tags and keep this <a href="">link text</a> ?

Answer (score 6):

```
extension String{
    var htmlStripped : String{
        return self.replacingOccurrences(of: "<[^>]+>", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
    }
}
```

Happy Coding

Answer (score 5):

I prefer to use a regular expression than to use NSAttributedString HTML conversion, be advised that is pretty time consuming and need to be run on the main thread too.
More information here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/1524613-initwithdata

For me this made the trick, first I remove any CSS inline styling, and later all the HTML tags. Probably not solid as the NSAttributedString option, but way faster for my case.

```
extension String {
    func withoutHtmlTags() -> String {
        let str = self.replacingOccurrences(of: "<style>[^>]+</style>", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
        return str.replacingOccurrences(of: "<[^>]+>", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: this leaves for example script contents

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5**

```
extension String {
    public func trimHTMLTags() -> String? {
        guard let htmlStringData = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) else {
            return nil
        }
    
        let options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey : Any] = [
            .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
            .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
        ]
    
        let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: htmlStringData, options: options, documentAttributes: nil)
        return attributedString?.string
    }
}
```

Use:

```
let  str = "my html <a href='https://www.google.com'>link text</a>"

print(str.trimHTMLTags() ?? "--") //"my html link text"
```

Comment: Source: https://gist.github.com/hashaam/31f51d4044a03473c18a168f4999f063#gistcomment-3137487

Comment: This removes new lines as well. it's not the perfect answer

Answer (score 2):

swift 4 :

```
extension String {
    func deleteHTMLTag(tag:String) -> String {
        return self.replacingOccurrences(of: "(?i)</?\(tag)\\b[^<]*>", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
    }

    func deleteHTMLTags(tags:[String]) -> String {
        var mutableString = self
        for tag in tags {
            mutableString = mutableString.deleteHTMLTag(tag: tag)
        }
        return mutableString
    }
}
```

Comment: or you can use like this:func deleteHTMLTag() -> String {
        return self.replacingOccurrences(of: "(?i)</?\\b[^<]*>", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
    }

Comment: This regex doesn't strip out html code for me. Example string: "<b>Cats like</b> doing something". Didn't investigate more for the reason why it doesn't work. But text.replacingOccurrences(of: "<[^>]+>",....)  works for my simple cases.

Answer (score 2):

Updated for Swift 4:

```swift
guard let htmlStringData = htmlString.data(using: .unicode) else { fatalError() }

let options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey: Any] = [
                .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html
                .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.unicode.rawValue
             ]

let attributedHTMLString = try! NSAttributedString(data: htmlStringData, options: options, documentAttributes: nil)
let string = attributedHTMLString.string
```

Comment: you're missing a ',' after the .documentType: param

Answer (score 1):

Was able to achieve mild success using `XML` [Event-Based Processing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/xml_processing_and_modeling) with [XMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/xmlparser), available on all platforms with `Foundation`.

#### Pros

- This solution is arguable more performant than using regular expressions.
- Safer, as some folks already mentioned, `HTML` is not a regular language.
- Thread safe (no need to run it on the main thread).

#### Cons

- `HTML` is not `XML`, although it is very similar you may need to clean up your `HTML` before trying to parse it as `XML`.
- For example: `<br>` and `<hr>` will make the parsing fail, but `<br />` and `<hr />` will be parsed as a `\n`.
- It is a delegate based API, forcing you to conform to `NSObject` protocol and event based processing.
- `XMLParser` has not been updated in a long time, thus lacks a lot of new Swift capabilities that we would like to have.
- [XMLDocument](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/xmldocument) is a more recent and flexible API also provided with `Foundation`, but it is only available on macOS.

---

For my own use case I made a class that enables me to use `async/await` and asynchronous processing.

Feel free to tweak for your own use case, maybe improving the cleaning process of the original `HTML` string.

#### Solution

```swift
import Foundation

final class Parser: NSObject, XMLParserDelegate {
    private(set) var result = ""
    private var finished: (() -> Void)?
    private var fail: ((Error) -> Void)?
    private var content = ""

    init(html: String) async throws {
        super.init()
        
        result = try await withUnsafeThrowingContinuation { [weak self] continuation in
            // tweak here as needed
            let clean = html
                .replacingOccurrences(of: "<!DOCTYPE html>",
                                      with: "",
                                      options: .caseInsensitive)
                .replacingOccurrences(of: "<br>",
                                      with: "\n",
                                      options: .caseInsensitive)
                .replacingOccurrences(of: "<hr>",
                                      with: "\n",
                                      options: .caseInsensitive)
            
            let xml = XMLParser(data: .init(("<xml>" + clean + "</xml>").utf8))
            self?.finished = { [weak self] in
                xml.delegate = nil
                self?.fail = nil
                self?.finished = nil
                
                guard let content = self?.content else { return }

                continuation
                    .resume(returning: content
                        .trimmingCharacters(in:
                                .whitespacesAndNewlines))
            }
            
            self?.fail = { [weak self] in
                xml.delegate = nil
                self?.fail = nil
                self?.finished = nil
                xml.abortParsing()

                continuation
                    .resume(throwing: $0)
            }
            
            xml.delegate = self
            
            if !xml.parse(),
                let error = xml.parserError {
                self?.fail?(error)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func parserDidEndDocument(_: XMLParser) {
        finished?()
    }
    
    func parser(_: XMLParser, parseErrorOccurred: Error) {
        fail?(parseErrorOccurred)
    }
    
    func parser(_: XMLParser, validationErrorOccurred: Error) {
        fail?(validationErrorOccurred)
    }
    
    func parser(_: XMLParser, foundCharacters: String) {
        content += foundCharacters
    }
}
```

#### Usage and Examples

Using some of the examples already given on this post

```swift
let string = "<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <body> <h1>My First Heading</h1> <p>My first paragraph.</p> </body> </html>"

let result = try await Parser(html: string).result
// My First Heading My first paragraph.
```

```swift
let string = "LCD Soundsystem was the musical project of producer <a href='http://www.last.fm/music/James+Murphy' class='bbcode_artist'>James Murphy</a>, co-founder of <a href='http://www.last.fm/tag/dance-punk' class='bbcode_tag' rel='tag'>dance-punk</a> label <a href='http://www.last.fm/label/DFA' class='bbcode_label'>DFA</a> Records. Formed in 2001 in New York City, New York, United States, the music of LCD Soundsystem can also be described as a mix of <a href='http://www.last.fm/tag/alternative%20dance' class='bbcode_tag' rel='tag'>alternative dance</a> and <a href='http://www.last.fm/tag/post%20punk' class='bbcode_tag' rel='tag'>post punk</a>, along with elements of <a href='http://www.last.fm/tag/disco' class='bbcode_tag' rel='tag'>disco</a> and other styles. <br />"

let result = try await Parser(html: string).result
// LCD Soundsystem was the musical project of producer James Murphy, co-founder of dance-punk label DFA Records. Formed in 2001 in New York City, New York, United States, the music of LCD Soundsystem can also be described as a mix of alternative dance and post punk, along with elements of disco and other styles.
```

```swift
let string = "my html <a href=\"\">link text</a>"

let result = try await Parser(html: string).result
// my html link text
```