# How to remove all the html from a string in swift

Tags: html, swift

Consider this string value:

```
LCD Soundsystem was the musical project of producer <a href="http://www.last.fm/music/James+Murphy" class="bbcode_artist">James Murphy</a>, co-founder of <a href="http://www.last.fm/tag/dance-punk" class="bbcode_tag" rel="tag">dance-punk</a> label <a href="http://www.last.fm/label/DFA" class="bbcode_label">DFA</a> Records. Formed in 2001 in New York City, New York, United States, the music of LCD Soundsystem can also be described as a mix of <a href="http://www.last.fm/tag/alternative%20dance" class="bbcode_tag" rel="tag">alternative dance</a> and <a href="http://www.last.fm/tag/post%20punk" class="bbcode_tag" rel="tag">post punk</a>, along with elements of <a href="http://www.last.fm/tag/disco" class="bbcode_tag" rel="tag">disco</a> and other styles. <br />
```

How can all html tags be removed in Swift?

So the result has to be:

```
LCD Soundsystem was the musical project of producer James Murphy, co-founder of dance-punk label DFA Records. Formed in 2001 in New York City, New York, United States, the music of LCD Soundsystem can also be described as a mix of alternative dance and post punk, along with elements of disco and other styles.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stripping out html tags from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25983558/stripping-out-html-tags-from-a-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use a regular expression, notice the one I've created:

```
    var str = "LCD Soundsystem was the musical project of producer <a href='http://www.last.fm/music/James+Murphy' class='bbcode_artist'>James Murphy</a>, co-founder of <a href='http://www.last.fm/tag/dance-punk' class='bbcode_tag' rel='tag'>dance-punk</a> label <a href='http://www.last.fm/label/DFA' class='bbcode_label'>DFA</a> Records. Formed in 2001 in New York City, New York, United States, the music of LCD Soundsystem can also be described as a mix of <a href='http://www.last.fm/tag/alternative%20dance' class='bbcode_tag' rel='tag'>alternative dance</a> and <a href='http://www.last.fm/tag/post%20punk' class='bbcode_tag' rel='tag'>post punk</a>, along with elements of <a href='http://www.last.fm/tag/disco' class='bbcode_tag' rel='tag'>disco</a> and other styles. <br />"



    let regex:NSRegularExpression  = NSRegularExpression(
        pattern: "<.*?>",
        options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive,
        error: nil)!


    let range = NSMakeRange(0, countElements(str))
    let htmlLessString :String = regex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(str,
        options: NSMatchingOptions.allZeros,
        range:range ,
        withTemplate: "")


    println(htmlLessString)
```

It converts:

```
"LCD Soundsystem was the musical project of producer <a href='http://www.last.fm/music/James+Murphy' class='bbcode_artist'>James Murphy</a>, co-founder of <a href='http://www.last.fm/tag/dance-punk' class='bbcode_tag' rel='tag'>dance-punk</a> label <a href='http://www.last.fm/label/DFA' class='bbcode_label'>DFA</a> Records. Formed in 2001 in New York City, New York, United States, the music of LCD Soundsystem can also be described as a mix of <a href='http://www.last.fm/tag/alternative%20dance' class='bbcode_tag' rel='tag'>alternative dance</a> and <a href='http://www.last.fm/tag/post%20punk' class='bbcode_tag' rel='tag'>post punk</a>, along with elements of <a href='http://www.last.fm/tag/disco' class='bbcode_tag' rel='tag'>disco</a> and other styles. <br />"
```

to

```
"LCD Soundsystem was the musical project of producer James Murphy, co-founder of dance-punk label DFA Records. Formed in 2001 in New York City, New York, United States, the music of LCD Soundsystem can also be described as a mix of alternative dance and post punk, along with elements of disco and other styles."
```

the only thing is that I've converted all double quotes(") to single quotes and then apply the regex, otherwise I needed to escape them all using `"\"`

**Update:**

I also tried escaping all double quotes by using `"\"` and the result was still the same:

new string I used was:

```
"LCD Soundsystem was the musical project of producer <a href=\"http://www.last.fm/music/James+Murphy\" class=\"bbcode_artist\">James Murphy</a>, co-founder of <a href=\"http://www.last.fm/tag/dance-punk\" class=\"bbcode_tag\" rel=\"tag\">dance-punk</a> label <a href=\"http://www.last.fm/label/DFA\" class=\"bbcode_label\">DFA</a> Records. Formed in 2001 in New York City, New York, United States, the music of LCD Soundsystem can also be described as a mix of <a href=\"http://www.last.fm/tag/alternative%20dance\" class=\"bbcode_tag\" rel=\"tag\">alternative dance</a> and <a href=\"http://www.last.fm/tag/post%20punk\" class=\"bbcode_tag\" rel=\"tag\">post punk</a>, along with elements of <a href=\"http://www.last.fm/tag/disco\" class=\"bbcode_tag\" rel=\"tag\">disco</a> and other styles. <br />"
```

and result:

```
"LCD Soundsystem was the musical project of producer James Murphy, co-founder of dance-punk label DFA Records. Formed in 2001 in New York City, New York, United States, the music of LCD Soundsystem can also be described as a mix of alternative dance and post punk, along with elements of disco and other styles."
```

Comment: Please avoid trying to parse html with regular expression, as html is not a regular language : http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1283385

Answer (score 3):

Here is CjCoaxs code rewritten for Swift 2.0:

```
var str = "LCD Soundsystem was the musical project of producer <a href='http://www.last.fm/music/James+Murphy' class='bbcode_artist'>James Murphy</a>, co-founder of <a href='http://www.last.fm/tag/dance-punk' class='bbcode_tag' rel='tag'>dance-punk</a> label <a href='http://www.last.fm/label/DFA' class='bbcode_label'>DFA</a> Records. Formed in 2001 in New York City, New York, United States, the music of LCD Soundsystem can also be described as a mix of <a href='http://www.last.fm/tag/alternative%20dance' class='bbcode_tag' rel='tag'>alternative dance</a> and <a href='http://www.last.fm/tag/post%20punk' class='bbcode_tag' rel='tag'>post punk</a>, along with elements of <a href='http://www.last.fm/tag/disco' class='bbcode_tag' rel='tag'>disco</a> and other styles. <br />"

let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "<.*?>", options: [.CaseInsensitive])

let range = NSMakeRange(0, input.characters.count)
let htmlLessString :String = regex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(input, options: [],
    range:range ,
    withTemplate: "")

print(htmlLessString)
```

Comment: Please avoid trying to parse html with regular expression, as html is not a regular language : stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1283385

Answer (score 2):

Here is code for Swift 3.0:

```
do {
        let regex =  "<[^>]+>"
        let expr = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex, options: NSRegularExpression.Options.caseInsensitive)
        let replacement = expr.stringByReplacingMatches(in: originalString, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, comment.characters.count), withTemplate: "")
        //replacement is the result
    } catch {
        // regex was bad!
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [SwiftSoup](https://github.com/scinfu/SwiftSoup) it's easy

```
do{
    let html = "LCD Soundsystem was the musical project of producer <a href="http://www.last.fm/music/James+Murphy" class="bbcode_artist">James Murphy</a>, co-founder of <a href="http://www.last.fm/tag/dance-punk" class="bbcode_tag" rel="tag">dance-punk</a> label <a href="http://www.last.fm/label/DFA" class="bbcode_label">DFA</a> Records. Formed in 2001 in New York City, New York, United States, the music of LCD Soundsystem can also be described as a mix of <a href="http://www.last.fm/tag/alternative%20dance" class="bbcode_tag" rel="tag">alternative dance</a> and <a href="http://www.last.fm/tag/post%20punk" class="bbcode_tag" rel="tag">post punk</a>, along with elements of <a href="http://www.last.fm/tag/disco" class="bbcode_tag" rel="tag">disco</a> and other styles. <br />"
    let doc: Document = try SwiftSoup.parse(html)
    return try doc.text()
}catch Exception.Error(let type, let message)
{
    print("")
}catch{
    print("")
}
```