# How to clean and parse HTML text and tags from a XML with Swift?

Tags: html, ios, xml, swift, parsing

I am parsing an XML from a webpage in my app. Inside the XML is a "**description**" item:

[image]

which has the following content:

[image]

**GOAL**:

I have to parse the "**description**" text by cleaning most of the HTML tags and extractiong the LOREM_IPSUM parts.

**QUESTIONS:**

Q1. Is generating such XML "content" bad practice? (I am not a web developer)

Q2. Is there a framework which might help me?

(So far I tried [Kanna](https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna) and [WMFeedParser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser))

Q3. Is there another way which doesn't involve me doing the parsing? (I mean when the XML is generated)

**OPTIONAL:**

I have also thought of finding a "content-div". However, inside that content div are like 5-10 other divs and all end with the standard < / div > which makes counting the a real pain. Also, this is only in this one "item", others are different...

So far it seems to me that this XML is poorly generated and that cleaning it up to present the text is a huge efford.

Any suggestion is welcome. Please feel free to correct me. Thanks :).

Comment: If the "dirty" XML HTML tags are never used by any application and you own XML generation, the best approach would be to clear up the XML within its creation. Not only you make it easier for any application to read it, you also save network traffic and post processing by getting rid of a considerable amount of garbage.

Comment: I agree with you, but I don't have access to it :/

Comment: If all you need is plain text with no formatting, have you tried [stripping all HTML tags with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25984103/2752041)?

Comment: Il give it a shot, but I think that there will be a lot garbage left...

Comment: Not quite. if you remove everything that stars and ends with `<...>` all you'll have left will be whitespace and raw text. After clearing the HTML tags try [trimming](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26797958/2752041) your String and you should have a clean result.