# How can I remove html tags from a string?

Tags: html, ios, swift2

I have a string that contains in it html code
 `let htmlString = <p style=\"text-align: right;\"> text and text`

and I want to ignore the html codes and have a string with only the text.

thank you.

Comment: Can you give an example of what output you want?

Comment: for <p style=\"text-align: right;\"> hello world </p> i want only hello world

Comment: Given the html '<p style=\"text-align: right;\">' What exactly do you want the end result to look like? is it like this **pstyletext-alignright**? I think it would be very helpful to give a little more info and a code example or  at least pseudo code example...

Comment: <p style=\"text-align: right;\">bold**this is the text i want at the end**bold.</p>\r\n<p style=\"text-align: right;\">&nbsp;</p>\r\n<p style=\"text-align: right;\"><iframe style=\"border: 0;\" src=\"https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3379.7103462239456!2d34.8005598845438!3d32.10411322529605!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0000000000000000%3A0x65b0972a8a5cebaa!2z157XldeW15nXkNeV158g15TXpNec154i15c!5e0!3m2!1siw!2sil!4v1450093273412\" width=\"316\" height=\"166\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen=\"allowfullscreen\"></iframe></p>

Comment: You want to strip the tags and get the plain text out.  Unfortunately it isn't as simple as it could be because HTML doesn't always comply with XML rules, but most modern HTML should be pretty close.  As a start, simply loop through the string one character at a time.  If you are 'outside' a tag then add the character to your output string.  If you are 'inside' a tag don't.  Naively, you are 'inside' a tag when you see a '<' and you are back outside once you see '>' - give that a try and see how you go, but reliable text extraction in all cases isn't trivial

Comment: can you add me on skype orim553? 
i cant realy understand from chat.

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/25984103/5362916

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove html tag from string by using `NSAttributedString`.

Please find the below code :

```
let htmlString = "<p style=\"text-align: right;\"> text and text"

    do {
        let encodedData = htmlString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        let attributedOptions : [String: AnyObject] = [
            NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
            NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: NSUTF8StringEncoding
        ]
        let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil)

        print("final strings :",attributedString.string)

    } catch {
        fatalError("Unhandled error: \(error)")
    }
```

Hope it works for you!!!

> You can also create String extension for reusability:

```
extension String {
init(htmlString: String) {
    do {
        let encodedData = htmlString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        let attributedOptions : [String: AnyObject] = [
            NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
            NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: NSUTF8StringEncoding
        ]
        let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil)
        self.init(attributedString.string)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Unhandled error: \(error)")
    }
  }
}
```

Swift 3.0 - (Xcode 8.2) Update

```
extension String {

    var normalizedHtmlString : String {

        do {
            if let encodedData = self.data(using: .utf8){
                let attributedOptions : [String: AnyObject] = [
                    NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSHTMLTextDocumentType as AnyObject,
                    NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: NSNumber(value: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                ]
                let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil)
                if let stringNormalized = String.init(attributedString.string){
                    return stringNormalized
                }
            }
        }
        catch {
            assert(false, "Please check string")
            //fatalError("Unhandled error: \(error)")
        }
        return self
    }
}
```

And call the htmlString method :

```
let yourHtmlString = "<p style=\"text-align: right;\"> text and text"
let decodedString = String(htmlString:yourHtmlString)
```

Comment: While this works there are some gotchas to be aware of.  It will only work on the main thread, if you use it on a background thread you may see random crashes.  Performance is terrible if you are going to be calling this a lot.  The reason for both of these is it spins up a UIWebView to perform the conversion.

Answer (score -1):

You may try using -[NSAttributedString  initWithData:options:documentAttributes:error:];

```
+ (NSAttributedString*)attributedStringForHTMLStrippingWithHTMLString:(NSString*)htmlString error:(NSError**)error
{
    NSAttributedString          *result                 = nil;
    NSMutableAttributedString   *attributedString       = nil;
    NSData                      *htmlStringData         =   [htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary                *options                =   @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                                                              NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)};


    attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:htmlStringData
                                                               options:options
                                                    documentAttributes:nil
                                                                 error:error];



    result = [attributedString copy];

    return result;
}

+ (NSString*)stripStringOfHTMLTags:(NSString*)htmlString
{
    NSString            *result             =   nil;
    NSError             *error              =   nil;
    NSAttributedString  *attributedString   =   [self attributedStringForHTMLStrippingWithHTMLString:htmlString error:&error];

    result = [attributedString string];

    return result;
}
```

Comment: He is asking the question for swift2. Answer should be in swift2.

Answer (score -3):

Try using a css file like so:

html-file:

```
<p id="myText" />
```

css-file:

```
#myText
{
text-align: right;
}
```