# How to remove html tags from received JSON data that is shown in SwiftUI's List view?

Tags: html, ios, json, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to get a book data description with a clean string which is currently in a raw JSON file. I've managed to get the data such as titles of the book, child trees, and descriptions. But while fetching the description, the data is in HTML tags such as

.. etc. The below image shows what I'm currently getting as data. [image: The arrow shows the description part where all the HTML tags are formatted]

and here is my code as below which I have used to call JSON book data and showed in SwiftUI's lists.

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct nesteddemo_newApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var book: Book = Book()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            
            // alternatively
            List {
                ForEach(book.bookContent) { bookContent in
                    Section(header: Text(bookContent.title)) {
                        OutlineGroup(bookContent.child, children: \.child) { item in
                            Text(item.title)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            ForEach(book.bookContent) { bookContent in
                VStack {
                    Text(bookContent.title)
                    List(bookContent.child, children: \.child) { item in
                        Text(item.title)
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
            .onAppear {
                loadData()
            }
    }
    
    func loadData() {
        do {
            if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "સાગર મંથન", withExtension: "json") {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                book = try JSONDecoder().decode(Book.self, from: data)
            }
        } catch {
            print("error: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    
    
    struct Book: Identifiable, Codable {
        let id = UUID()
        var bookTitle: String = ""
        var isLive: Bool = false
        var userCanCopy: Bool = false
        var bookContent: [BookContent] = []
        
        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case bookTitle = "book_title"
            case isLive = "is_live"
            case userCanCopy = "user_can_copy"
            case bookContent = "book_content"
        }
    }
    
    struct BookContent: Identifiable, Codable {
        let id = UUID()
        var title, type: String
        var child: [Child]
    }
    
    struct Child: Identifiable, Codable {
        let id = UUID()
        var title, type: String
        var child: [Child]?
    }
    
    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since this is from a bundled text file then why not open it in a text editor and remove the html tags once and for all using Find & Replace?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54439470/1801544 ?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson . There are lots of similar JSON books with such format which are locally stored, also such JSON books will be coming from server for the user. So i'm looking for way to either pass that data into Wkwebview or programatically hide/ remove it while  View load.

Comment: I understand, well the link in the comment above looks like a way forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
func attributedString(from str: String) -> AttributedString {
    if let theData = str.data(using: .utf16) {
        do {
            let theString = try NSAttributedString(data: theData, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil)
            return AttributedString(theString)
        } catch {  print("\(error)")  }
    }
    return AttributedString(str)
}
```

and replace Text(item.title) with Text(attributedString(from: item.title))

credits: @workingdog