# How to fix formatted text in UILabel (Swift)?

Tags: swift, swift5

I have a request and it gives me a formatted text as you can see in the picture. Maybe you know how to properly fix it (remove all this ,  etc), because l have only a probably bad idea to do something like `if label.contains..., remove`

Thank you so much[image]

Comment: There are HTML tags. Either interpret them (with (NS)AttributedString) to make some part bold as I see the tag, or remove them (with possible help of NSAttributedString) But when I see `ScoresRoot(summary: "...")`, I'm wondering if that's not just the description of the `struct` `ScoresRoot`. How did you populate the label exactly?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25983558/stripping-out-html-tags-from-a-string

Answer (score 0):

This is HTML data. You have to convert your HTML data to plain text data.

```
extension Data {
    var html2AttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: self, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            print("error:", error)
            return  nil
        }
    }
    var html2String: String { html2AttributedString?.string ?? "" }
}

extension StringProtocol {
    var html2AttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        Data(utf8).html2AttributedString
    }
    var html2String: String {
        html2AttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }
}
```

Now show your data in some label or wherever you want to show your data.

```
label.text = item.itemDescription.html2String
```