# Swift NSDataDetector to detect links picks up brackets </p> as part of the link

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, nsdatadetector

I am using the following to detect links and their range in a string:

```
let toParse = """
<td>Here's a few links which I want to test on:<p>https://news.ycombinator.com/ask</p>
<p>https://news.ycombinator.com/show</p>
<p>https://news.ycombinator.com/lists</p>
Will it work?
</td>
"""

print("Parse: \(toParse)")
do {
    let detector = try NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)
    let matches = detector.matches(in: toParse, options: .reportCompletion, range: NSMakeRange(0, toParse.count))

    for match in matches {
        print("url: \(match.url!) at \(match.range.lowerBound), \(match.range.length)")
    }
} catch let error {
    debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

This prints:

```
url: https://news.ycombinator.com/ask%3C/p%3E at 50, 36
url: https://news.ycombinator.com/show%3C/p%3E at 90, 37
url: https://news.ycombinator.com/lists%3C/p%3E at 131, 38
```

As you can notice, it's picking the `</p>` as part of the link. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Are the HTML tags important? Can you remove all of them first, and then find URLs?

Comment: I did try that and it does work but it seems a bit of a workaround. Why is the NSDataDetector detecting the tags in the first place?

Comment: it’s not designed to work on HTML in the first place. See its documentation - it’s designed to work on natural language text.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdatadetector says « You should only use NSDataDetector on natural language text »

You can load your HTML in a web view and then enable Data Detectors on it, or parse the HTML with NSAttributedString first.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Seems like it's only meant to be used on natural language. Can you expand on what you mean by "or parse the HTML with NSAttributedString first"? As far as I know, NSDataDetector can't run on NSAttributedString and needs to be run on String no?

Comment: @sudoExclaimationExclaimation See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34490303/5133585). There is a `string` property on `NSAttributedString`.