# Remove HTML elements from NSAttributedString

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring

```
let string = "To find out more, click <a href=\"example.com\"><span>here</span></a> to go to our help page"
let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: string)
uitextview.attributedText = attributedString
```

Now the `string` constant is dynamically created so I can't manipulate it's content directly. And I'm displaying the `attributedString` in a **UITextView** and after the user made some changes, I want to edit the `attributedString` and remove the `a` tag from the `attributedString`

I want to remove the `a` tag and it's HTML contents except it's text. And I can't do something like this:

```
attributedString.string
```

Because there are other HTML elements that might be in the `attributedString` which might loose it's attributes

What I have done so far:

```
let range = NSRange(location: 12, length: 14)
let attributedText = uitextview.attributedText!
let subAttrText = attributedText.attributedSubstring(from: range) // "more, click he"
let subText = subAttrText.string
let mutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attributedText)
mutableString.replaceCharacters(in: range, with: subText)
uitextview.attributedText = mutableString
```

**Expectation:** `To find out re to go to our help page`

**Result:** `To find out <a href=\"example.com\"><span>re</span></a> to go to our help page`

How can I make the link text to be converted to just plain text?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25983558/stripping-out-html-tags-from-a-string

Comment: @koen... No, I'm trying to remove the HTML elements from `NSAttributedString` while in your suggestion, it's trying to remove HTML elements from `String`

Comment: If you want to remove only the link, you need to enumerate that attribute (with `enumerateAttribute(.link, ...)`), and remove it.

Comment: I don't understand your complaint, if I extract the string with `attributedString.string` and then apply the solution suggested by @koen I get the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a way to figure it out

```
let range = NSRange(location: 12, length: 14)
let attributedText = uitextview.attributedText!
let subAttrText = attributedText.attributedSubstring(from: range) // "more, click he"
let subText = subAttrText.string
let mutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attributedText)
mutableString.deleteCharacters(in: range)
mutableString.insert(subText, at: range.location)
uitextview.attributedText = mutableString
```

Comment: What if your string changes, how will you know what the `range` will be?

Comment: @koen... The `range` I used is just for the purpose of this question and based on the `string`... Now both the `string` and the `range` are gotten dynamically