# Swiftui and Wordpress Rest API HTML decoding issue

Tags: json, wordpress, rest, swiftui

i am trying to implement the newsblog from a website in to the app which is with the REST API in wordpress. I am able to decode slugs and other `strings` and `INTs`, however the title and content are built in HTML. When i use the extension, mentioned in this post [Stripping out HTML tags from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25983558/stripping-out-html-tags-from-a-string) , it gives me an error when trying to force unwrap the title name in a `TEXT`. I think that the list is trying to force unwrap the title, before it is loaded from the JSON API, but cannot find any info on this. the error:

`[error] precondition failure: setting value during update: 52280`

This is my View:

```
      List(JSONuser, id: \.id) { JSONuser in
        NavigationLink {
              ScrollView {
                  Text("\(JSONuser.title.rendered.stripOutHtml() ?? "Title unavaillable")")
                    .bold()
                    .font(.title)
                    .padding(.top, 10)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 7)
                Divider().modifier(dividerViewStyle())
                Text(JSONuser.content.rendered)
                  .padding(.bottom, 30)
                  .padding(.horizontal)
              Spacer()
            }
        } label: {
          Section("\(JSONuser.title.rendered)") {
//            VStack {
//              Text(JSONuser.title)
//            }
//            print(JSONuser.id)
          }.padding(.vertical)
            .bold()
        }
      }.listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
       .padding(.bottom, 20)
```

The JSON Viewmodel:

```
class apiCall {
    func getUsers(completion:@escaping ([JSONuser]) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.db-professional.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts") else {
          print("invalid URL")
          return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
            let JSONuser = try! JSONDecoder().decode([JSONuser].self, from: data!)
            print(JSONuser)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(JSONuser)
            }
        }
        .resume()
    }
}
```

and the model:

```
struct Rendered: Codable {
     var rendered: String
}


struct JSONuser: Codable, Identifiable {
  let id = UUID()
  let title: Rendered
  let content: Rendered
}
```

Comment: Observation: you are confusing yourself and the compiler by using`JSONuser` for everthing, e.g. to represent a type, then an instance, then what, a type or an array in List? Use the standard convention, uppercase for types and lowercase for instances, and give arrays a representative name.

Comment: Could be that it is a text: when i use the ```Print```, it works fine with force unwrapping. Doing this in a ```Text```, makes it crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, `title.rendered` does not have html, but `content.rendered` does.
Since there so much confusion with your naming, try using the following example code, works well for me.

If however, your `stripOutHtml()` does not behave properly it will crash your App, in the `Text` field view. Some solutions in your link, do not behave well (crash) in ios.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showProgress = true
    @State var users = [JSONuser]()  // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {  // <-- here
            if showProgress {
                ProgressView("Fetching data")
            } else {
                List(users) { user in  // <-- here
                    NavigationLink {
                        ScrollView {
                            VStack {
                                Text(user.title.rendered)  // <-- here
                                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                                    .bold()
                                    .font(.title)
                                    .padding(.top, 10)
                                    .padding(.horizontal, 7)
                                Divider()//.modifier(dividerViewStyle())
                                Text("\(user.content.rendered.stripOutHtml() ?? "Content unavailable")")  // <-- here
                                    .foregroundColor(.green)
                                    .padding(.bottom, 30)
                                    .padding(.horizontal)
                                Spacer()
                            }
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Section("\(user.title.rendered)") {
                            //            VStack {
                            //              Text(user.title)
                            //            }
                        }.padding(.vertical).bold()
                    }
                }
                .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
                .padding(.bottom, 20)
            }
        }
        .task {
            await loadData()
            showProgress = false
        }
    }
    
    func loadData() async {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.db-professional.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts") else {
            print("bad URL")
            return
        }
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            users = try JSONDecoder().decode([JSONuser].self, from: data)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
 
}

// for testing only
extension String {
    func stripOutHtml() -> String? {
        return self.replacingOccurrences(of: "<[^>]+>", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
    }
}

struct Rendered: Codable {
     var rendered: String
}

struct JSONuser: Codable, Identifiable {
  let id = UUID()
  let title: Rendered
  let content: Rendered
}
```

Comment: I changed the naming immediately you observed it, i adjusted the code you provided with the naming and it works like a charm. The Extension whas the one i ended up using as well, however, iFrames still show the code and do not get stripped out. But thanks a lot for your help!